# Open Source Library for generating concrete types from interfaces during runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation

I'm working on something that needs to take in a contract (specified as an interface), and create a instance on the fly, without any formally defined concrete class that meets this interface.

An example of the syntax is like this:

```
IExampleMessage message = MessageBuilder.Create<IExampleMessage>(x => {
   x.PropertyA = "Test";
   x.PropertyB = 5;
});
```

I've seen other .NET libraries and frameworks offer behavior like this (NServiceBus comes to mind), and I'm wondering if there is a 3rd party library that abstracts the runtime code gen away. I thought Castle DynamicProxy would be a place to look, but this seems focused entirely on proxying and intercepting, and does not seem to expose the code generation aspect.

I could write up a implementation that uses Reflection.Emit to create the class on the fly, however I'd rather use a solid open source library if one exists.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I saw similar code in BLTookit

Comment: I'm curious: How would interfaces with methods be supported? How do you intend to specify a custom implementation of a method with that syntax?

Comment: Interfaces with methods are not supported

Answer (score 2):

Impromptu interface is what you need:- http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/

I've used it to create [polymorphic types in .NET](http://blog.abodit.com/2011/05/class-free-persistence-multiple-inheritance-in-c-sharp-mongodb/).

You could also look at [Clay](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/08/16/clay-malleable-c-dynamic-objects-part-1-why-we-need-it.aspx).

Comment: I was trying to stay away from Dynamic. However that stuff is pretty cool.

Comment: @Jonathan-Holland in the use-case you are describing wouldn't require you to actually see any usage of dynamic in your code when using impromptu (though it will be happening behind the scenes). Example implementation: `public T Create<T>(Action<T> init) where T:class {var message= new ExpandoObject().ActLike<T>(); init(message); return message;}`

Answer (score 1):

What about the mocking libraries - NMock, and RhinoMocks?

You can add implementations to the concrete types using stubs/expectations as well.

Rhino in particular has a nice lambda based syntax for the kind of thing that you want.

Does this not full fill your needs?

Something like this?

```
IExampleMessage message = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IExampleMessage>();
message .Stub(x => x.PropertyA).Return("Text")    
message .Stub(x => x.PropertyB).Return(5)
```